# How do I use values from a yaml file into json file in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, json, docker, asp.net-core, yaml

I am working on project in which the environment variables are stored in a .yaml file.
Is there a way through which I can use them in my appsettings.json file without making major changes in the code?

Comment: You can convert yaml to json with something like `yq`.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools available that convert YAML to JSON files and you can use the configuration values in appsettings.json. Another option is to enable Yaml configuration support. You can use the `NetEscapades.Configuration.Yaml` NuGet package, which supports reading from AppSettings.Yaml file.

Here is the code.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder => 
            {
                builder.AddYamlFile("appsettings.yml", optional: false);
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

You can find more details here - https://github.com/andrewlock/NetEscapades.Configuration