# How to externalize variables in .net application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, docker, yaml

I referred to the below documentation in order to externalize variables in .net application.
https://github.com/tgropper/env-settings-net/blob/master/README.md

The objective is to read values from .yaml file and use it in appsettings.json with the help of placeholders. In my case it seems like appsettings.json is not able to fetch the value. What could be the possible solution for this?

Comment: Please edit your post so it shows what you've done, what you expect should happen and what actually happens.

Comment: I had a similar issue, You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72550342/how-do-i-use-values-from-a-yaml-file-into-json-file-in-asp-net/72554563#72554563).